# Hamming code error correction multiple bits

Tags: digital-logic, noise, telecommunications

If we send a message from a sender and the noisy channel produces 2 bits with error can we detect both bits using hamming code or is it just for 1 bit?

Comment: If by *"detect both bits"* you mean identifying which bits were changed, no. You can detect 100% of the possible 2 bits errors, without being able to identifying them. You could detect and correct all 1 bit errors.

Comment: yes but we can identify which bits was changed if the erroneous bit is 1 right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision to **"only detect"** or trying to **"correct"** the errors changes what you can do with 100% coverage:

- if error correction is implemented, the code can **correct** (identify which bit flipped) all 1 bit errors
- if only error detection is implemented, the code can detect all 1 bit and 2 bits errors, without being able to identify which one(s) flipped

The behavior is the same regardless if the error results in a bit '1' or a bit '0'.

As @BenVoigt noted in the comments, if you add a single parity bit to the message (taking all the data bits and Hamming Code bits as inputs) you can *correct* all 1 bit errors **and** *detect* all 2 bits errors.

Comment: Note that the above tradeoff applies to any code with minimum distance 3 (like the Hamming code has).  A code with minimum distance 4 can detect (but not correct) all 2 bit errors while simultaneously correcting all single-bit errors.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks. I've added your contribution.